# Devise & Factorybot authentication for RSpec POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, factory-bot

Setup using devise_token_auth, Factorygirl, and RSpec.

Trying to sign in a user, and make a post request, but I am getting 401 unauthorized response.

*/spec/controllers/scripts_controller_spec.rb*

```
module Api::V1
RSpec.describe ScriptsController, type: :controller do

  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user)}

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {name: 'YWoodcutter', skill: 'Woodcutting', bot_for: 'TRiBot', game_for: "Oldschool Runescape 07", user_id: user.id}
  }
...
describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Script" do
        sign_in user
        expect {
          post :create, params: {script: valid_attributes}
        }.to change(Script, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "renders a JSON response with the new script" do
        sign_in user
        post :create, params: {script: valid_attributes}
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
        expect(response.content_type).to eq('application/json')
        expect(response.location).to eq(script_url(Script.last))
      end
    end
```

RSpec Test Results:
Failures:

> 1) Api::V1::ScriptsController POST #create with valid params creates
>   a new Script
>        Failure/Error:
>          expect {
>            post :create, params: {script: valid_attributes}
>          }.to change(Script, :count).by(1)
>
> ```
>    expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
>  # ./spec/controllers/scripts_controller_spec.rb:72:in `block (4 levels) in <module:V1>'
> ```
>
> 2) Api::V1::ScriptsController POST #create with valid params renders
>   a JSON response with the new script
>        Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
>          expected the response to have status code :created (201) but it was :unauthorized (401)
>        # ./spec/controllers/scripts_controller_spec.rb:80:in `block (4 levels) in '

Curious as to why the POST #create didn't fire. I essentially used the same values from my seed data, which works fine.

Also wondering why request is unauthorized, even after calling Devise's signn_in user.

Thank you.

Edit:
The Devise wiki mentions [mappings](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29) should I be calling this line somwhere?

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Comment: I feel like there is something wrong with how you have written this `describe "POST #create" do`

Answer (score 1):

devise_token_auth requires you to include the token in the headers, I put a helper in the support folder:

```
def auth_request(user)
  sign_in user
  request.headers.merge!(user.create_new_auth_token)
end
```

and then in your specs call `auth_request user` instead of `sign_in user`

Comment: I tried this, but I don't have access to the "request" variable. --> `undefined method `headers' for nil:NilClass`